# Input field has a default margin

Tags: html, css

The image is positioned right but the input field appears to have a margin top of 20 px or so but it's never set to have that anywhere in my CSS.

HTML:

```
<div id="vault_chat_header">
   <span><img src="<%tdir%>img/default_avatar.png" alt="Default Avatar"  class="user_avatar" /></span>
   <span><input type="text" class="vault_chat_text_field" /></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vault_chat_text_field {
    background-color: red;
    height: 48px;
    width: 92%;
}

.user_avatar {
    background-color: red;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
}
```

DOCTYPE:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: So explicitly set `margin: 0` in the CSS for the `.vault_chat_text_field` elements.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work though that's the weird part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give the input

```
vertical-align: top;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CLGNH/